# height of HorizontalFieldManager

Tags: blackberry, simulator

How to display chatting data on horizontal field manager., because, i m not sure that how long my text length would be.  Like as we do chat in Gmail or facebook.

If is there any other way for displaying the chat data. so please let me know now.

Answer (score 1):

The HorizontalFieldManager will grow in height to whatever the height of the child field is (as long as the space is available).

Comment: Dear Sir, Thanks for your reply. I m not getting you properly. Please go through in detail of requirement. you know when we do chat in Gtalk or any other Messenger, there we don't know that. how many character will be involve in chatting.  for example: if i will say, Hi pawan, then it require only online. but if i will type 10 line. then??? how could i know that its height. because i m storing chat text in labelField. and i have to put the labelfield inside horzontalField. this chat will be dynamically, even how many horizontalfield would have require. i don't know.

Comment: Put each chat message in a HFM and put all of those in a VerticalFieldManager

Comment: Hello jprofitt: Thanks for your reply.  I have already applied this same exact thing that you share with me. But project not working. i mean all HFM get same height. that i don't want. i want diff hfm with diff height at run time.....

Comment: They should each adjust to the height of the Field inside of it.